# Identifying questions with the most/least answers

Tags: discussion, tags

If I type the following in the search bar:

```
answers:3 is:question [stata]
```

I get back all questions in [stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata) with three or more answers.

Is there a way to identify the questions in a **particular tag** with the *most* and/or *least* answers?

Bonus points if the results are also ordered.

*The least number of answers* can be either one or zero. Ideally an answer should cover both.

Comment: try doing a big number then reducing by one each time you click search

Comment: Please be clearer about 'the least'. Shouldn't questions with *no answers* win that category?

Comment: _Summons rene_ wait until magic happens

Comment: @kayess: surely anyone can write `select question.id as [Post Link], question.score, count(answer.id) as [# answers] from posts as question outer join posts as answer on question.id = answer.parentid where question.tags like '%<##tagname##>%' group by question.id, question.score order by count(answer.id) desc`? :-P

Comment: I downvoted because I think the post isn't useful as its very unlikely a search like this would ever be neede

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to run queries against a recent copy of the database; this is great for running more complex searches.

I've written up a query that orders questions by the number of answers, given a tag:

```sql
select question.id as [Post Link], question.score, question.answercount
from posts as question 
inner join posttags on posttags.postid = question.id
inner join tags on tags.id = posttags.tagid 
where tags.tagname = '##tagname##'
order by question.answercount desc
```

This includes questions with no answers; if you want to limit it to questions with at least one answer add a `and question.answercount > 0` clause before the `order by` clause.

You can take a look a the [results for the `stata` tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/854690/questions-in-a-given-tag-ordered-by-number-of-answers?tagname=stata).

Personally, I don't think this kind of search is all that interesting. The number of answers to a post doesn't vary all that much, and questions with no or just one answer [vastly outnumber posts with more answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/854696?tagname=stata#graph):

[image: Answers per question histogram for the stata tag]

Comment: Many thanks. I personally find this quite useful and i also learned something new as i had no idea that there is a Data Explorer.

Comment: Uuuhmmm, answercount is an attiribute of posts. and that like on tags gives you a full-table scan on a not so small table. Consider this instead: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/854732

Comment: @rene: facepalm. Indeed, I'll adjust.

Comment: @PearlySpencer you might like the [tutorial](http://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).

Comment: @rene Thank you, this is very helpful indeed. Stack Exchange Data Explorer was a really exciting discovery today!